# Issue in trying to fetch user playing track using https://github.com/zmb3/spotify in golang

Tags: go, oauth, spotify

```golang
package src

import (
    ctx "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "github.com/zmb3/spotify/v2"
    spotifyauth "github.com/zmb3/spotify/v2/auth"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
)

func CompleteAuth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    userID := r.URL.Query().Get("state")
    auth := spotifyauth.New(spotifyauth.WithRedirectURL(Env.RedirectUrl), spotifyauth.WithScopes(spotifyauth.ScopeUserReadCurrentlyPlaying), spotifyauth.WithClientID(Env.ClientID), spotifyauth.WithClientSecret(Env.ClientSecret))
    tok, err := auth.Token(ctx.Background(), userID, r)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Couldn't get token", http.StatusForbidden)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    client := spotify.New(auth.Client(ctx.Background(), tok))
    info, err := client.CurrentUser(r.Context())
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Couldn't get user", http.StatusForbidden)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    db.Set(userID, tok.AccessToken, 0)
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("You are logged in as: %s\n", info.DisplayName)))
}

func IndexPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("Hello!. Use /auth to login with spotify and /current to get your current playing song"))
}

func CurrentPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    userid := r.URL.Query().Get("user_id")
    if userid == "" {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        w.Write([]byte("You need to provide a user_id"))
        return
    }
    token, _ := db.Get(userid).Result()
    auth := spotifyauth.New(spotifyauth.WithRedirectURL(Env.RedirectUrl), spotifyauth.WithScopes(spotifyauth.ScopeUserReadCurrentlyPlaying), spotifyauth.WithClientID(Env.ClientID))
    fmt.Println(token)
    client := spotify.New(auth.Client(ctx.Background(), &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: token}))
    go RefreshToken(userid, client)
    user, err := client.PlayerCurrentlyPlaying(r.Context())
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error getting current playing song: %s", err.Error())))
        return
    }
    response := PlayingInfo{
        Playing: user.Playing,
        Info:    nil,
    }
    if user.Playing {
        artists := make([]string, len(user.Item.Artists))
        for i, artist := range user.Item.Artists {
            artists[i] = artist.Name
        }
        response.Info = &PlayingResponse{
            SongName:      user.Item.Name,
            Artists:       strings.Join(artists, ", "),
            Link:          user.Item.ExternalURLs["spotify"],
            Duration:      user.Progress,
            TotalDuration: user.Item.Duration,
            Thumb:         user.Item.Album.Images[0].URL,
        }
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error encoding JSON:", err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func AuthSpotify(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    userID := r.URL.Query().Get("user_id")
    if userID == "" {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid Params use ?user_id=<user_id>", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    auth := spotifyauth.New(spotifyauth.WithRedirectURL(Env.RedirectUrl), spotifyauth.WithScopes(spotifyauth.ScopeUserReadCurrentlyPlaying), spotifyauth.WithClientID(Env.ClientID))
    url := auth.AuthURL(userID, oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte(url))
}

func RefreshToken(userId string, client *spotify.Client) string {
    token, _ := db.Get(userId).Result()
    if token == "" {
        log.Println("User not logged in")
        return ""
    }
    auth := spotifyauth.New(spotifyauth.WithRedirectURL(Env.RedirectUrl), spotifyauth.WithScopes(spotifyauth.ScopeUserReadCurrentlyPlaying), spotifyauth.WithClientID(Env.ClientID), spotifyauth.WithClientSecret(Env.ClientSecret))
    c, err := spotify.New(auth.Client(ctx.Background(), &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: token})).Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error refreshing token:", err)
        return ""
    }
    db.Set(userId, c.AccessToken, 0)
    return c.AccessToken

}
```

Tthis is my complete oauth flow code.

I am getting user id from user and trying to generate token and storing it to reuse it and get user current played songs.

I am trying to store oauth token to reuse in other requests in future or even to refresh it after an hour.

What I am stuck at is:

> Error getting current playing song: spotify: couldn't decode error: (46) [User not registered in the Developer Dashboard

I don't know why am I getting this error. It works fine initially when user try to get current track after that it returns this error; does it mean I can't re-use token of other user with my client creds? Is there any other way to reuse or store any info which could get user track in each req instead of making them login again and again?

If anyone know why am i experiencing this issue please let me know of it